# Installing ubuntu percise or ringtail on a toshiba sateillite l45 s4687

Tags: installation

Was just wondering if anyone has had any issues installing Ubuntu Precise on a Toshiba Satellite L45 S4687.And if you think Ring tail will run.I don’t know what the specs are yet.But.It is running Vista now.I will be doing a fresh install of Ubuntu.Thanks.It will have 2 gigs ram.40 gig storage.Possibly more.No dual booting. I will be deleting Vista and installing Ubuntu.

Comment: "Try Ubuntu without changing anything"Sorry.That's the my noob showing.Thanks i'll try that

Comment: @user68186 Thanks!I been running Ubuntu on a Thinkpad T43 with 2GB for a few years and runs very well.I do very much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to find out if there will be any issues is to use the **Try Ubuntu without changing anything** option after booting from a Live USB/DVD.

2GB RAM should be OK for Ubuntu. If not, try Lubuntu, which needs less.

The new version of Ubuntu (13.04) will come out tomorrow. It is supposed to be slightly less resource hungry than the previous version. You may want to try that.

Hope this helps